# After returning the reference the data gets erased

Tags: c++, vector, reference, stdvector

I am somehow aware of returning by reference by this got me confused.

I have a function which returns a reference to a public field of class `BoardNode`, `std::vector<BoardNode> _neighboursVector`.

I also have a class `Board` which holds a `std::vector<BoardNode>`.

my member function goes like this:

```
const std::vector<BoardNode>& 
Board::getNeighboursVector(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const
{
    BoardNode node = this->getBoardNode(x, y);
    //...
    node._neighboursVector.push_back(...);
    //...
    return node._neighboursVector;
}
```

While debugging on return line I get the correct values in the vector but outside of this function I get empty vector. Why ?

```
std::vector<BoardNode> v = b.getNeighboursVector(5,5);
```

**EDIT**

`getBoardNode` definitions

```
const BoardNode & Board::getBoardNode(unsigned int rowIdx, unsigned int colIdx) const
{
//...
}

BoardNode & Board::getBoardNode(unsigned int rowIdx, unsigned int colIdx)
{
//...
}
```

Comment: How is `getBoardNode` declared?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`node` is a local object.  And by extension, `node._neighborsVector` is also a local object.  As a local object, it gets destroyed at the end of the function.  So you are returning a reference to a destroyed object.  That's undefined behavior.

Comment: Adding to that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope  : There is a massively upvoted answer which describes very nicely about scope and access.

Answer (score 2):

`node` is created on the stack (local to your function) and thus deleted at the end of the function. Since the reference you return is a field of `node` it is also deleted. Therefore you return a reference to a deleted object.

You should either return by value (in this case correctly implement the copy constructor - here for `std::vector` it's ok) or by pointer (created by new and don't forget to `delete` when you're done with the returned object).

Comment: You shouldn't return rvalue references to local object either.

Comment: Can't vote for this answer since it suggests returning a pointer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley you're right - it's been some time since I played with move.

Comment: @john: that's just absurd. C/C++ has pointers, it's a language feature. If the vector is long to build and has millions of entries it's really better to return pointer/smart-pointer instead of copied object.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough, obviously the pointed object has to be allocated with `new`

Comment: Well smart pointer is another thing. The implication of the answer is a regular pointer since you mention delete.

Comment: Smart pointers are more convenient and secure. That doesn't make regular pointers invalid.